# wordpress проблема с выводом архивов произвольных записей по категориям

Tags: wordpress

Я создал произвольную таксономию category_goods
далее создал произвольый тип записей товары и связал с этими таксономиями.

**в single.php могу вывести категорию товара вот этой функцией**

```
debug(get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'category_goods')); // и оно работает, выводит масси с инфой категории.
```

**вот код регистрации:**

**reg_new_taxonomy.php(есть инклуд в functions.php)**

```
<?php 
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomy' );
function create_taxonomy(){
    // список параметров: http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_taxonomy_labels
    register_taxonomy('category_goods', array('goods_post_type'), array(
        'label'                 => 'Категория товара', // определяется параметром $labels->name
        'labels'                => array(
            'name'              => 'Категория',
            'singular_name'     => 'Категория товара',
            'search_items'      => 'Поиск категорий товара',
            'all_items'         => 'Все категории товаров',
            'view_item '        => 'Показать категорию товара',
            'parent_item'       => 'Родительская',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Родительская',
            'edit_item'         => 'Редактировать категорию товара',
            'update_item'       => 'Обновить категорию товара',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить новую категорию товара',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Новое имя Категории товара',
            'menu_name'         => 'Категории товаров',
        ),
        'description'           => '', // описание таксономии
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_ui'               => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_menu'          => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'show_tagcloud'         => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'show_in_rest'          => null, // добавить в REST API
        'slug'                  => null,
        'rest_base'             => null, // $taxonomy
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        //'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'rewrite'               => true,

        'capabilities'          => array(),
        'meta_box_cb'           => null, // callback функция. Отвечает за html код метабокса (с версии 3.8): post_categories_meta_box или post_tags_meta_box. Если указать false, то метабокс будет отключен вообще
        'show_admin_column'     => true, // Позволить или нет авто-создание колонки таксономии в таблице ассоциированного типа записи. (с версии 3.5)
        '_builtin'              => false,
        'show_in_quick_edit'    => null, // по умолчанию значение show_ui
    ) );
}

add_action('init','good_cat_for_goods');
function good_cat_for_goods(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category_goods','goods_post_type');
}

function get_category_goods_link($id) {
    return get_term_link($id,'category_goods');
}
?>
```

**reg_new_post_type.php(есть инклуд в functions.php)**

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );

function register_post_types(){

    register_post_type('goods_post_type', array(

        'label'  => "goods",

        'labels' => array(

            'name'               => 'Товары', // основное название для типа записи

            'singular_name'      => 'Товар', // название для одной записи этого типа

            'add_new'            => 'Добавить товар', // для добавления новой записи

            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление товара', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.

            'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование товара', // для редактирования типа записи

            'new_item'           => 'Новый товар', // текст новой записи

            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть товар', // для просмотра записи этого типа.

            'search_items'       => 'Искать товар', // для поиска по этим типам записи

            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено

            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине

            'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)

            'menu_name'          => 'Товары', // название меню

        ),

        'description'         => '',

        'public'              => true,

        'publicly_queryable'  => true, // зависит от public

        'exclude_from_search' => true, // зависит от public

        'show_ui'             => true, // зависит от public

        'show_in_menu'        => true, // показывать ли в меню адмнки

        'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // по умолчанию значение show_in_menu

        'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public

        'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7

        'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7

        'menu_position'       => 4,

        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-feedback', 

        //'capability_type'   => 'post',

        //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи

        //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав

        'hierarchical'        => false,

        'supports'            => array('title','editor','thumbnail'), // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'

        'taxonomies'          => array('category_goods'),

        'has_archive'         => true,

        'rewrite'             => true,

        // 'query_var'           => true,

    ) );

}



?>
```

На странице goods - шаблон page-goods.php я вывожу только категории(category_goods) с ссылками. должно работать так. кликнул на категорию и открывается страница с записями, которые относятся к этой категории.

вот как выглядит вывод в шаблоне

```
  <div class="container">
          <div class="row"> 
                        <?php


$categories = get_categories( array(

                'taxonomy'     => 'category_goods',

                'type'         => 'goods_post_type',

             ) );

    ?>
          <?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>
            <?php 
             debug(get_category_goods_link($category->term_id));
             debug($category);
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 margin-col">
              <div class="goods-categories-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
                  <a href="#">
                          <?php 
                    $id_img = get_term_meta($category->term_id,'id-cat-images', true); 
                    if(!empty($id_img)){
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image($id_img,'full');
                    }else{
                      echo '<img src="https://dargor.info/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/KAM08723.jpg" alt="">';
                    }
                  ?> 
                 </a>
                 <div><?php echo $category->name;?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
```

когда перехожу по ссылке, которая выдает эта функция 
`debug(get_category_goods_link($category->term_id));`

**reg_new_taxonomy.php**

```
 function get_category_goods_link($id) {
        return get_term_link($id,'category_goods');
    }
```

WordPress говорит ничего не найдено. В чем может быть проблема ?

Ссылки на архив записей работают(так как не выдает 404.php). Но по какой-то причине Wordpress не находит записи по категориям. и говорит не найдено.

**SOS люди добрые с:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы прежде чем добавлять опции, посмотрели бы что они вообще значат, `exclude_from_search` зачем добавлен? уберите его

[Тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type#exclude_from_search-logicheskij) все расписано что означает та или иная опция

И обновите пути через настройки->постоянные ссылки

Comment: офигеть. как я не заметил это

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, к стати, я сделал немного по другому, я просто сделал Wp_Query() по $_GET['category_goods'], так можно делать ?)

Comment: сделал запрос в базу в ручную, вместо WP, получается

Comment: Как хотите. Вы получается доп. запрос к БД делаете. Не помню но дефолтные запросы вроде как кешируются, что снижает нагрузку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. :)